# SQLAlchemy - cache table obj locally

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, offline-caching

I'm querying an existing read-only database with SQLAlchemy, and wonder if there is a way to **cache the queried table object locally (in an automatic way)** so that I can use it later. The main reason of this need is not to lock the database while my script is running (e.g. I have to keep a session connected to wait for user's response), and the database is read-only so I really don't need the modified data to be synchronized back.

Right now I'm working through a solution to convert the queried results into pd.DataFrame, but it would be nice to keep the advantage of SQLAlchemy where the queried result can retain it's structure rather than being converted to a flat table in pd.DataFrame.

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and still learning. Any suggestions about the solution or if I miss some major features already provided in SQLAlchemy package would really be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the results of a query or the actual table to query against?

Comment: @IanWilson I meant to say 'the results of query', and I have been using eager loading so I assume all the information including the children are queried once and loaded into the query result object.